# Brackets in chemical formulas

Tags: stoichiometry, atoms, notation

When you have brackets such as $\ce{Zn(NO3)2}$, if there is a coefficient around the formula such as $\ce{2Zn(NO3)2}$, how would you read this? Would there be 2 zinc atoms, 4 nitrogen and 12 oxygen atoms if I am multiplying that out correctly?

Comment: It means $\ce{Zn(NO3)2}$ contains a $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ion and 2 $\ce{NO3-}$ ions

Comment: @Atticus283blink the coefficient indicates that there are two units of that molecule.

Comment: @JM97 right i know that but would how does the 2 affect the (NO3)2 ? Would this means there are 4 N and 12 O atoms?

Comment: @Atticus283blink yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

$\ce{2Zn(NO3)2}$ can be interpreted differently, depending on the context.
The '2' outside of the parenthesis could either refer to two *molecules* or two *moles* of substance. In either case, the chemical formula tells you the same thing: that there are two units of $\ce{NO3-}$ for every unit $\ce{Zn^2+}$.

I would write it as zinc (II) nitrate, (read as 'zinc-two-nitrate) The roman numeral (II) refers to the oxidation state of the zinc ion, which is $+2$.